# Drop Down Menu floats above page when browser window is shrunk

Tags: javascript, css, dropdown, navbar, styling

In mobile view, if I already have the drop down menu open, and then I start dragging the browser window upwards to shrink window, the drop down doesn't stay where its supposed to. Instead it floats over the navbar *(or too far below the navbar if I drag the window all the way down on my monitor)*. How do I make it stay in one spot?

- Live website Netlify link: https://visionary-belekoy-9a3354.netlify.app/
- Repo: https://github.com/DeBoer753/cbm-APP/tree/main
- Code: (DropDown.jsx)

```
// REACT:
import { useState } from 'react'

// ROUTER:
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

// DATA:
import { MenuItems } from './MenuItems' // this deconstructs and finds the variable holding the data

// CSS:
import './DropDown.css' 

export default function DropDown() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false)

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click)

  return (
    <>
      <ul onClick={handleClick} className={click ? 'dropdown-menu clicked' : 'dropdown-menu'}>
        {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}><Link className={item.cName} to={item.path} onClick={() => setClick(false)}>{item.title}</Link></li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

```
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  right: 260px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: start;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(28, 27, 27) 0%, rgb(26, 23, 23) 100%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover {
  background: rgb(173, 173, 173);
}

.dropdown-menu.clicked {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that on mobile devices you cannot shrink or drag the browser window – it's always in fullscreen mode

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
@media(max-width: 960px) {
    .navbar {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 9;
    }
}
```

I've tried to use this code on your site and it works (navbar sticks to the top when scrolling)